# Strcpy Copies to other char array

Tags: c

I am trying to convert hexadecimal to string but I am facing strange issue when using strcpy then its append String to another variable.

Below is my code

```
int hex_to_int(char c) {
int first = c / 16 - 3;
int second = c % 16;
int result = first * 10 + second;
if (result > 9) result--;
return result;
}

int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d) {
int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
int low = hex_to_int(d);
return high + low;
}


void hexToString(char st[16], int length, char string[16]) {
char buf = 0;
char tempHTS[16] = {""};
char tempHTS1[16] = {""};

for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sprintf(tempHTS, "%c", hex_to_ascii(buf, st[i]));
        strcat(tempHTS1, tempHTS);
    } else {
        buf = st[i];
    }
}
strcpy(string,tempHTS1);
}

void decodeToHex(unsigned char readingreg[16], int length, char hexString[16]) {
char tempDTH[16];
char tempDTH1[16]={""};

for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
    sprintf(tempDTH, "%x", readingreg[j]);
    strcat(tempDTH1, tempDTH);
}
strcpy(hexString,tempDTH1);
}

int main() {
unsigned char readingreg[9];
readingreg[0] = 0x74;
readingreg[1] = 0x68;
readingreg[2] = 0x69;
readingreg[3] = 0x73;
readingreg[4] = 0x20;
readingreg[5] = 0x74;
readingreg[6] = 0x65;
readingreg[7] = 0x73;
readingreg[8] = 0x74;
char hexString[16];
char actualString[16];

decodeToHex(readingreg, sizeof(readingreg), hexString);
hexToString(hexString, (int) strlen(hexString), actualString);

printf("\n%s\n", actualString);
printf("\n%s\n", hexString);

return 0;
}
```

below is output

this test

7468697320746573this test

in second printf "this test" gets automatically append to hex string.
I not getting the reason. please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't leave space for the null terminator.

Comment: @Kevin thanks how stupid to me

Comment: Unrelated but still ugly to not say wrong: This `char tempDTH1[16]={""};` should either be `char tempDTH1[16]="";` or `char tempDTH1[16]={'\0'};` or `char tempDTH1[16]={0};`. All three way of initialisation set `tempDTH1` to all zeros, which `char tempDTH1[16]={""};` does not.

Comment: Related to debugging you might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Another bean-counter.  Why are trying to size char arrays exactly?  It's somewhere round 16-20 bytes, so [128].  Job done, no counting, no overrun, no NUL terminator bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readingreg` has 9 bytes, which means you need at least `9*2+1 = 19` characters to store a hex string of that data (2 for each byte and 1 for the null terminator). `hexString` only has 16 bytes, so you end up writing out of bounds which leads to undefined behavior.